# Jmeter command line option issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am running a load test using jmeter command line and saving the result into csv file using -l command line option. After the test is completed, i see the data in the csv and while i upload it to a view result tree and try to check the failure response data in the response section, i dont see any response data noted in there. Is there something am missing here?

i have the following command

```
<path to jmeter bat> -n -t <jmx loc> -l <loc of result.csv> -j <path to jmeterlog> -Gparam1 -Gparam2 -Gparam3 -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.label=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Gjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -e -o <Reportpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. By default JMeter uses [CSV format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) for saving test metrics
2. CSV format is not suitable for storing response data due to eventual delimiters and line breaks. Moreover as per [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) chapter it's not recommended to store response data.

If you really need to save response data you need to switch JMeter's .jtl file format to XML and instruct JMeter to store it, it's controllable via the following properties:

- `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format` - defaulting to `csv`
- `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data` - defaulting to `false`

So you need to amend your command line to override these properties like:

```
<path to jmeter bat> -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true ......
```

in order to make the changes permanent add the corresponding lines to *user.properties* file

More information:

- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Another option is adding a separate Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and configure it to save response data into a separate file:

[image]

Comment: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property
An error occurred: Error in NonGUIDriver Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property
errorlevel=1

Comment: @Dimitri T: I see the error as above when setting as xml

Comment: Dashboard can be generated only from CSV files